# Twilio - Voice Redirect to same URL

Tags: c#, twilio

Based on the documentation for the Voice [Redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect) command, it should be possible to redirect to a relative URL (for a GET request) and in my case the same URL.

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
response.Say("Hello World");
response.Redirect(null, Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Get);
```

Which produces the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="man">Hello World</Say>
    <Redirect method="GET"></Redirect>
</Response>
```

The expected behavior is correct and it will redirect back to the initial URL, but the query params sent on the redirects appear to continually add more (and more) query params.  Here are some snippets from ngrok:

1st Request
[image: 1st Request]

2nd Request (redirect)
[image: 2nd Request (redirect)]

Trying to redirect to the URL using relative path, assuming **primary** is my endpoint:

```
response.Redirect(new Uri("../primary", UriKind.Relative), Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Get);
```

Results in an exception when creating the XML - **This operation is not supported for a relative URI.**

Is there a better way to redirect to the same relative URL?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

**Update**

This bug has been fixed in Twilio C# version 5.9.5. A [serializer was implemented for URLs](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/pull/409) to be used in place of calling `AbsoluteUri`. Please update and try this out.

**original answer**

I'll start with a caveat, I'm not a C# developer so this is my read of the situation and source code.

It seems that this is a bug in the C# library. Specifically, we say that a relative URL is allowed, however when working with the URL [the library calls on the `AbsoluteUri`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/master/src/Twilio/TwiML/Voice/Redirect.cs#L45) property which raises an [`InvalidOperationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri(v=vs.110).aspx) when called on a relative URL.

If this is the case, it would be best to [raise an issue against twilio-csharp](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues) explaining what is going on. I'd recommend that you raise the issue yourself so that you can be alerted when work is done on it.

Let me know if that helps at all.